# Getting error when trying to click a button inside the div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello there I am getting the the validation error when trying to click the button inside the div eg try clicking button "one " here 
     https://jsfiddle.net/Reginald/q5z0zwuf/

```
       $(function(){
                    $('textarea').on('keypress keydown keyup click', function(){
                      if ($(this).val().length >=0)
                        {
                           $('button').show().removeAttr('disabled');
                           $('.second').show(); 
                           $('.pstShr').show().removeAttr('disabled');                              
                           $('.transport').hide();

                            $('button.sign').on('click',function(){ 
                                $('.transport').show().removeAttr('disabled');
                                });


                        }
                      else                
                        {
                          $('button').hide().prop('disabled', true);
                          $('.second').hide();   
                          $('.pstShr').hide().prop('disabled',true);
                        }
                    });

                  $('#cancel').on('click', function(){                     
                    $('textarea').val('').trigger('keypress');
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Form is getting submitted. Add `type="button"` to both buttons. Default type is `submit`

Comment: flip thanks  it is ofine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `<button>` is in a form, the default behaviour is `submit`.

**[MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)**

> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Add `type="button"` to it.

Example :

```
<button type="button" id="post" style="display: none" disabled>POST</button>
```